# Ngx-color-picker hide color value from input

Tags: angular, input, colors, color-picker

I'm using this [color picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker) to allow a user set his color.

Is there any way I can hide the hex value from the input and only leave the background color?

[image]

I'd like to avoid using CSS if there are better options

```
<input class="form-control"
     name="textSearchColor"
     [(colorPicker)]="textSearchColor"
     [style.background]="textSearchColor"
     [(ngModel)]="textSearchColor"
/>
```

Comment: probably worthwhile to mention why you'd like to avoid css

Comment: I thought there was a more elegant solution using a built-in option. Guess I'll use color: transparent for that input after all...

Comment: I mean if you want to hide it then css is the way to go. If you want to remove it from the DOM it's not. Just throwing it out there to help you improve the question

Comment: Yeah I just want to hide the hex value. I should've been more specific

Comment: :) no it's fine it's just worthwhile to clarify. I haven't used Angular for a long time and I have no idea about this color-picker. Maybe there's a good "angular way" to do this. Otherwise, just throw a `display: none` on that element (presumably a span) either using stylesheets or programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but I  want to add one of the solutions. Just color input text the same as the background color.

```html
<input class="form-control"
     name="textSearchColor"
     [(colorPicker)]="textSearchColor"
     [style.background]="textSearchColor"
     [style.color]="textSearchColor" <----
     [(ngModel)]="textSearchColor"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type="button"` to the input tag. It works for me.